# How to dynamically add fields using java script?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

**This is my code for another button along with the fields to be included**

```
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
<div class="invoice-items"><div class="invoice-item">
<div class="item-description"><div class="autocomplete">
<input type="text" placeholder="Description" maxlength="255" 
class="input"> <ul class="ac-dropdown" style="display: none;">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item-line-2">
<div class="flex item-price">
<label for="i-item_price_0" class="label-addon-left">USD</label> 
<input type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_0" autocomplete="off" 
class="input input-addon-left">
</div> <!----> 
<div class="item-actions">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" >Add Another Item</button>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
if (counter == limit)  {
alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
}
else {
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = "Item" + (counter + 1) + " <input type="text" 
placeholder="Description" maxlength="255" class="input"> <ul class="ac-
dropdown" style="display: none;">";
document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
counter++;
}
}
```

**Here is the javascript . i am unable to give a click . Infact there is no response to my button clicks**

Comment: Did you do some research on your own? Because that title sounds like it has been answered a bunch of times.

Comment: Do you want to add the whole tab again? Moreover, kindly provide the code of javascript that you have tried to achieve this and share the error/issue you are facing...

Comment: Yes i have created my javascript but it isnt working. Wait i ll provide the javascript

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

For a start you should pay attention to quote closures.

Restruct the innerHTML part with this

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "Item" + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' 
placeholder='Description' maxlength='255' class='input'> <ul class='ac-
dropdown' style='display: none;'>";
```

You might also need a closing tag, a.k.a /> at the end of the input instead of just >

Answer (score 0):

Attach click event to your button:

```
 <button type="submit" onclick="addInput()">Add Another Item</button>
```

And update the lines here :

```
 newdiv.innerHTML = "Item" + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' placeholder='Description' maxlength='255' class='input'><ul class='ac-dropdown' style='display: none;'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an event listener attached to your button. So when you click, the browser is not being told what to do. I suggest something like this...

```js
// Add event listener to the submit button
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addNewItem);

function addNewItem(e) {
  // Prevent default action (not sure if this is needed since I can't see all of your code)
  e.preventDefault();

  // Check if list items are at limit yet
  const invoiceItems = document.querySelector('.invoice-items'); // The 'list' of items
  const counter = invoiceItems.children.length; // The number of items in the list
  if (counter >= 3) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {

    // Create a new list item    
    const newItem = document.createElement('div');

    // Add the appropriate class and add children elements to new list item
    // You may want to clean up your code a bit, there is an unused <ul> and
    // an unused HTML comment, but I just copied what you already had
    newItem.className = 'invoice-item';
    newItem.innerHTML = '<div class="item-description"><input type="text" placeholder="Description" maxlength="255" class="input"><ul class="ac-dropdown" style="display: none;"></ul></div></div><div class="item-line-2"><div class="flex item-price"><label for="i-item_price_' + counter + '" class="label-addon-left">USD</label><input type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_' + counter + '" autocomplete="off" class="input input-addon-left"></div><!----><div class="item-actions"></div></div>';

    // Attach the new list item to the list
    invoiceItems.appendChild(newItem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    <div class="invoice-items">
      <div class="invoice-item">
        <div class="item-description">
          <div class="autocomplete">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" maxlength="255" class="input">
            <ul class="ac-dropdown" style="display: none;">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-line-2">
          <div class="flex item-price">
            <label for="i-item_price_0" class="label-addon-left">USD</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_0" autocomplete="off" class="input input-addon-left">
          </div>
          <!---->
          <div class="item-actions">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Add Another Item</button>
  </div>
```